# Flutter Http requests in local network

Tags: flutter, dart

My friend has a rest api on his laptop that he accesses with loopback ip address.
The way my friend accesses the api with software on pc is:

```
GET /resource-path HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
```

I have an app on flutter that has to take data from his rest api.
Is there a package on flutter where we can be in the same network and i manually send http request to his ip address or use something like broadcast address to send it to him?
I have looked through pub.dev for packages but they all require url for requests

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting from an emulator use ip 10.0.2.2 to connect with the host computer, if you are using a real device, you can get the computer's ip address using ipconfig command (windows) and connect to that ip using your network, you may have to adjust the firewalls though. you don't need url to access api, ip address is enough (for http requests, https will require url). and you don't need and extra package as well, you can use the inbuild http package